# Newly opened windows do not appear in the active virtual desktop | Ubuntu 20.04, KDE Plasma 5.18.7

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Problem: I installed KDE Plasma on Ubuntu 20.04, then added virtual desktops. Certain more frequently used applications will appear in a different virtual desktop than desired (the active desktop).

Firefox appears in desktop 2, Konsole in 1, and Dolphin in 4. I have perused multiple articles previous to this and have not yet found the solution.

The only thing that does work is removing virtual desktops altogether and that is obviously not a preferred solution.

How would I go about setting applications to **always** open in the active desktop (i.e. the one I am in currently)?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Right click on the toolbar of a problem application and hover over '**More Actions...**', then click '**Configure Special Window Settings**'.

[image]

In the popup window in the '**Size and Position tab**' change the Desktop option to '**Apply Initially**' and '**All Desktops**' and hit ok to save the settings.

[image]

While this worked for me, I cannot fully guarantee this solution for you, you may have to play around with the settings more.